# Using React.useState and useSelector together causes selector to continuously fire

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

I'm trying to create a page where users can create a social media post. When they upload images it will display them below a text box and then they can fill in the text associated with those photos.

The issue I'm running into is that every time the local state (which is where I'm storing the state for the text field) of the functional component changes (when I type) , the selector is run and I could see this by adding the print statement to the selector. I am also getting this error in the debugger `Native TextInput(asdfasdfasdf) is X events ahead of JS - try to make your JS faster.` whenever I type in the text input quickly. The images also appear and disappear rapidly when this happens until it catches up and is no longer behind. I'm guessing that this is a result of the selector running and then the image mapping having to run again and re-render the images.

I'm not sure if you're just not supposed to mix useState and useSelector in the same component or how best to avoid this. Here is a simplified version of my code. Thanks!

```
const TestComponent: React.FC<any> = (props: any) => {
  const [textValue, setTextValue] = React.useState("");
  const previewImages = useSelector(
    (state: any) => {console.log("USING SELECTOR"); return state.photoReducer.uploadedPhotos},
  );
  
  return (
   <>
    <TextInput
      onChangeText={setTextValue}
      value={textValue}
    />
    previewImages.map((previewImageObject: any) => {
      return <Image key={uuid()} source={previewImageObject.uri}/>
     });
    );
  </>
}
export default TestComponent;
```

Comment: `key={uuid()}` isn't a way to define a stable React key across renders... in other words, every time this component renders you are telling React that all the preview images are different and they are all unmounted and mounted again. Find a way to provide stable ids or some intrinsic property of the images so you have a more stable render cycle.

Comment: @DrewReese Thank you! That fixed the flashing of images. Also did some reading up on keys and that makes more sense now. Still interested in why the selector still fires every time but I now know that the selector was not the problem.

Comment: Welcome. I answered with a suggested implementation to provide stable ids for React keys at the same time you were responding. Add added a brief explanation about the `useSelector` hook running each render as well. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`key={uuid()}` isn't a way to define a stable React key across renders... in other words, every time this component renders you are telling React that all the preview images are different and they are all unmounted and mounted again.

I suggest using some intrinsic property of the images, like the `uri` property. If this isn't possible then you will need to augment the images data. Use an `useEffect` to update a local cache of preview images augmented with a GUID.

```
const TestComponent: React.FC<any> = (props: any) => {
  const [textValue, setTextValue] = React.useState("");
  const [previewImages, setPreviewImages] = React.useState([]);

  const uploadedPhotos = useSelector((state: any) => state.photoReducer.uploadedPhotos);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setPreviewImages(uploadedPhotos.map(image => ({
      id: uuid(), // <-- generate GUID
      image,      // <-- store image object
    })))
  }, [uploadedPhotos]);
  
  return (
   <>
    <TextInput
      onChangeText={setTextValue}
      value={textValue}
    />
    {previewImages.map((previewImageObject: any) => (
      <Image
        key={previewImageObject.id}           // <-- access id
        source={previewImageObject.image.uri} // <-- access image.uri
      />
    ))}
  </>
}
```

> Still interested in why the selector still fires every time

React hooks are called every render in the same order they are defined in. If you've an expensive call to your redux state you can create [memoized selectors](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect) that return the previous computed state chunk if the input selectors returned the same value as in the previous render.